# Programming Web Services for WebLogic Server

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic

I was trying to execute a simple Web Service example from a book:

```
package com.alsb.hello;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import weblogic.jws.WLHttpTransport;
import weblogic.jws.WSDL;

@WebService
@WSDL(exposed=true)
@WLHttpTransport(portName="HelloWorldSoapPort", serviceUri = "HelloWorldService", contextPath = "business/hello")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class HelloWorld {

    @WebMethod
    public String hello(String arg) {
        return arg + "z";
    }
}
```

But when i start the server (Weblogic 10.3.6) it happens the following error:

> Errors: The annotation weblogic.jws.WSDL is not allowed on
>   com.alsb.hello.HelloWorld because it is a JAX-WS type web service.

The same happens with the annotation **@WLHttpTransport**.

Could someone figure out where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

"Although this release of WebLogic Server supports both JAX-RPC 1.1 and JAX-WS 2.0 based Web Services, you can use the WebLogic-specific annotations only with JAX-RPC-based Web Services.", check [Overview of JWS Annotation Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webserv_ref/annotations.html#wp1038924) from Weblogic. Maybe this could be the reason.